# Calling public ApiGateway from ApiGateway in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, api-gateway

I have two api gateways - one public (**A**), another one in VPC (**B**) with `VPCEndpoint` configured to make calls to api gateways.

`VPCEndpoint` configuration:

```
  IotCoreApiGatewayVPCEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "execute-api:Invoke"
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt DbSecurityGroup.GroupId
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetAId
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetBId
```

The api gateway **B** is calling the api gateway **A** and I'm receiving 403-Forbidden error.

If I remove `VPCEndpoint` configuration, instead of 403 I receive timeout.

Calling the api gateway **A** from lambda without VPC works fine, CORS is enabled as well.

The similar issue is expressed here:

https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/

The article states that I have to set up an `Edge-Optimized Custom Domain Name` for ApiGateway and that requires using `ACM Certificates`.

Is there an easier way to solve this problem?
Can I just attach an id of security group with api gateway **A** access to the `VPCEndpoint`?

Server response:

```
{
  "Version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/json"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Length",
        "Value": [
          "23"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 403,
  "ReasonPhrase": "Forbidden",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Server",
      "Value": [
        "Server"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Date",
      "Value": [
        "Mon, 16 Dec 2019 11:25:43 GMT"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Connection",
      "Value": [
        "keep-alive"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-amzn-RequestId",
      "Value": [
        "09df4fdd-d26d-4266-b569-35d537488913"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-amzn-ErrorType",
      "Value": [
        "ForbiddenException"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-amz-apigw-id",
      "Value": [
        "Ey10qAA7DoEF-Ng="
      ]
    }
  ],
  "RequestMessage": {
    "Version": {
      "Major": 2,
      "Minor": 0,
      "Build": -1,
      "Revision": -1,
      "MajorRevision": -1,
      "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": {
      "Headers": [
        {
          "Key": "Content-Type",
          "Value": [
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Key": "Content-Length",
          "Value": [
            "104"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Method": {
      "Method": "POST"
    },
    "RequestUri": "https://{apigatewayUrl}api/Commands",
    "Headers": [],
    "Properties": {}
  },
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
}
```

Upd: Adding **edge-optimized custom domain name** as it was suggested in [article](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/), didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Does B have the proper IAM role to call A?

Comment: How are you invoking private API B - can you share the output of a curl command? Are you able to invoke public API A from inside a VPC (i.e. from an EC2 instance)

Comment: @franziga - A lambda not in VPC can call api **A** via Http without any additional permissions. It just sends an http request to web api address. I've added `apigateway:*` and `lambda:*` permissions for api **B**, but nothing has changed

@Suraj Bhatia - updated the question with server response

Comment: Does security group in VPC block outgoing http?

Comment: @franziga all outgoing http traffic is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred that an access to the public api gateway (and public Internet as well) was blocked until I added a Nat Gateway to my VPC. The solution is described here - https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12